# c# auto property VS 2005?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Do auto-properties work in VS 2005? I can't seem to get my C# classes to compile with them (same with the in-place initialisation). I have framework 3 sp1 installed. Are these features only available in VS 2008 or is there something I am doing wrong?

By in-place initialisation i mean the following:

```
SomeClass c = new SomeClass()
{
  Name = "",
  Value = 12345
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Automatically implemented properties and object initializers (the sample you showed) were both introduced in C# 3.0. Visual Studio 2005 only compiles C# 2.0.

For more on what came in which version (and which C# 3.0 features you can use when targeting .NET 2.0), see [my article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

No.  Autoproperties are a product of the 3.5 compiler and only VS2008 can understand them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use auto-properties in VS 2008 on projects that are targeted for .NET 2.0 as well.

You can also use lambda expressions and the var keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with the WPF/WCF add-on for VS2005, you can create 3.0 applications.  The compiler cannot utilize the 3.5 compiler though.

I used the add-on in order to create WPF applications when 3.0 released.  3.5 was exclusive to the 2008 IDE.

EDIT:
What I mean to sayis the compiler that is attached to the VS2005 debugger cannot utilize them and thus you get the error at compile-time.